# How to toggle layout_behavior behavior on and off programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

Let’s pretend the simple case for simplicity. I have a FloatingActionButton on which I add a layout_behavior. I need to be able to enable or disable the behavior programmatically. How do I do that? I originally add the behavior through xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/mine"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/default_message"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom"
    app:layout_behavior=“mywidget.ScrollingFABBehavior"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can retrieve the `LayoutParams` via

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
```

And that point you can either set the behavior directly with [setBehavior()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html#setBehavior(android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior)):

```
params.setBehavior(null);
```

Or get your instance of behavior and call a method to have it disable itself (that you make):

```
ScrollingFABBehavior behavior =
    (ScrollingFABBehavior) params.getBehavior();
// This is a method you write
behavior.setEnabled(false);
```